# jQuery change value of content inside parent sibling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to assign the range slider value inside the slider parent sibling

```js
var rangeSlider = function() {
    var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-
        value = $('.range-slider__value');

        slider.each(function() {

          value.each(function() {
            var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
            $(this).html(value);
          });

          range.on('input', function() {
            $(this).parents.siblings(value).html(this.value);
          });
        });
      };

    rangeSlider();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3 class="range-slider__value">0</h3>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
</div>
```

i added a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/GEErWm?editors=1010)

Comment: What problem are you having with it? Where is the code that tries to do this?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the code, i added it to my og question

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing brace for your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed your codepen, look at this

```
 var rangeSlider = function(){
      var slider = $('.range-slider'),
          range = $('.range-slider__range'),
          value = $('.range-slider__value');

      slider.each(function(){

        value.each(function(){
          var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
          $(this).html(value);
        });

        range.on('change', function(){
          $(this).parents().find(value).html(this.value);
        });
      });
    };

    rangeSlider();
```

Comment: just one minor change i would keep `range.on('input')` instead of 'chance' to see the scrubbing